# Связка 3 таблиц в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Есть 3 таблицы (jobs, proposals, user).

```
jobs:
-id
-description
...

proposals:
-id
-title
-job_id
-user_id
...

user:
-id
-username
...
```

Сейчас связываю таблицы jobs и proposals.

models/Job.php

```
public function getProposals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Proposal::className(), ['job_id' => 'id']);
}
```

и вывожу:

```
$obj = Job::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
foreach ($obj->proposals as $proposals){
...
}
```

Как мне связать еще proposals и user что бы в foreach вывести username из таблицы user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну по аналогии

```
models/Proposal.php
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}


$obj = Job::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
foreach ($obj->proposals as $proposals){
    $proposals->user;
...
}
```